How could I change all values in a dictionary by a percentage?
Is there a easy way to change every dictionary value by a percentage or do I have to loop through them all and change them by a percentage lets say 2%. So the first one that is 100 would change to 102% but the second that's 1000 would change by 20 so 1020.

See this.

Yes use a loop. [ask]

okay sorry for not asking a good question i should of researched better.

my_dict = {"a": 100, "b": 1000, "c": 500}
# Use dictionary comprehension to increase each value by 2%
my_dict = {key: value * 1.02 for key, value in my_dict.items()}
print(my_dict)

Or use the Pandas library:
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {"a": 100, "b": 1000, "c": 500}
df = pd.DataFrame(list(my_dict.items()), columns=['key', 'value'])

# Increase each value by 2%
df['value'] *= 1.02

my_dict = pd.Series(df.value.values, index=df.key).to_dict()
print(my_dict)


Gpt gave a very similar answer. Did you get this from chatgpt?

@Phix Surely not, that is against the rules isn't it?

Doesn't mean people won't do it. Seems very verbose for an answer to a simple question.

Of course not, I have now simplified this answer to make the result more clear.
